# How far away are we from a UV LED operating at around 100nm?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, light-emitting-diodes

So far, we are down to around 250nm for UV LEDs. If I could get one at around 100nm that would ionize air I would find it very useful. Any ideas on whether this wavelength is feasible for a LED?

Comment: Last I looked most UV LEDs had pretty broad spectra, so for the purposes you discussed in your last post it is not necessary for the peak to approach the value you need, you just need a non-negligible tail at those energies.

Comment: On the other hand, you need a new semiconductor with a band gap about 2.5 times bigger than the nitrides that are getting LEDs up to 250nm.  Lots of development would seem to be needed to get conducting insulators that can be doped both n and p type.